# Isomorphism of sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Given a smooth projective variety $X$ and a semiample and big $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor $D$.
We denote by $R:=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(nD))$.
Denote by $\tilde R(n)$ the quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$ defined by the 
$R$-module $R(n)$.

Do in general the isomorphism of sheaves $\tilde R(n) \simeq \mathcal{O}_X(nD)$
holds for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}$?